# Next row from dataset button only performing function once

Tags: c#, asp.net

I asked a question yesterday about paging through a data set using next / previous buttons displaying a single row in a forms text boxes. Since then I've managed to get the next button to go to the next row but only once. every subsequent click does nothing. here's some code.

The code that executes after the the user selects a search value and presses a value:

```
  public static int inc = 0;

  protected void ExecuteSelectCopies(string sName)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    try
    {
        string sql =
            "SELECT tblCopies.CopyID, tblSoftware.SoftwareName, tblCopies.AssetName, tblCopies.Location,"
            + " tblCopies.LicenceKey, tblCopies.OEM, tblCopies.State, tblCopies.InstallationDate"
            + " FROM tblCopies"
            + " INNER JOIN tblSoftware ON tblCopies.SoftwareID = tblSoftware.SoftwareID"
            + " WHERE tblSoftware.SoftwareName = @SoftwareName"
            + " ORDER BY tblCopies.CopyID";
        SqlDataAdapter adapterH = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand(sql, connectionHWM);
        adapterH.SelectCommand = select;
        select.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SoftwareName", sName));
        //open the connection
        connection.Open();
        dataSetH = new DataSet();
        adapterH.Fill(dataSetH, "Copies");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = "fetch Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }

    NavigateCopies();
}
```

The code that populates the text boxes for the first time:

```
    private void NavigateCopies()
{
    DataRow dRow = dataSetH.Tables[0].Rows[inc];
    TextBoxCopyID.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
    TextBoxSoftwareName.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
    DropDownListAssetName.SelectedItem.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
    DropDownListLocation.SelectedItem.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
    TextBoxLicence.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
    DropDownListType.SelectedItem.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString();
    DropDownListState.SelectedItem.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString();
    TextBoxInstall.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString();
    Session["ds"] = dataSetH;
    Session["increment"] = inc;
}
```

The next row button code:
    protected void ButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["ds"] != null)
        {
            dataSetH = (DataSet)Session["ds"];
            inc = (int)Session["increment"];
            inc++;

```
        if (inc != dataSetH.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
        {
            NavigateCopies();
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "No More Rows";
        }
    }
}
```

So when the Next button is pressed one it selects the next row. each subsequent click does nothing. The pages status bar symbol spins but the text boxes are not populated with the next record. I'm not sure if this has something to done with the fact the form is reloading but every example I've seen has a table or grid populated on load whereas my situation requires me to populate text boxes after user input. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

I have since edited the code. Its now working, allowing the next button to page through the whole data set. I shall create a catch on the button to prevent the user from going over the maximum rows now.

Comment: I would also Love to know how to remove the need for this to work without a copy of the navigate function in the button!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as same as you put `Session["ds"]`  need to put `inc` value as well

```
protected void ButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["ds"] != null)
    {
        int inc;
        if(Session["inc"]==null)
        {
          Session["inc"] =0;
        }
        if(int.TryParse(Session["inc"], out inc)
        {
            inc++;
            Session["inc"] = inc;
            DataSet dataSetH = (DataSet)Session["ds"];

            if (inc <= dataSetH.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
            {
                DataRow dRow = dataSetH.Tables[0].Rows[inc];
                TextBoxCopyID.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
                TextBoxSoftwareName.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
                DropDownListAssetName.SelectedItem.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
                DropDownListLocation.SelectedItem.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
                TextBoxLicence.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
                DropDownListType.SelectedItem.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString();
                DropDownListState.SelectedItem.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString();
                TextBoxInstall.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm i see what you mean about taking the inc. Give me a couple of minutes to try something out

Comment: OK I've got it! you were right about taking the inc value with me. I've reused the same navigate method for simplicity. I'll update my question with the solution now.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. I've shown my solution in my question, I was making it difficult for myself it seems. Your example showed me how I should approach it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Because you define inc variable in private scope , only you access first row 
you should public scope vaiable with static

```
          public static  int inc = 0 ;
```

and also set again DataSet :

```
            // put Session["ds"] need to put inc value as well your assign
```