# How to use Datarow with DataTable to populate radiobuttonlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I created one quiz sample code, in that I have one `label` and one `RadioButtonList` for question and answer,

```
 public DataSet GetDataSet(string query)
  {
      DataSet QuestionSet = new DataSet();
      DataTable QTable = new DataTable();
      QTable.Columns.Add("ROW_NUMBER");
      QTable.Columns.Add("QuestionNo");
      QTable.Columns.Add("Tname");
      QTable.Columns.Add("Tnumber");
      QTable.Columns.Add("question");
      QTable.Columns.Add("ans1");
      QTable.Columns.Add("ans2");
      QTable.Columns.Add("ans3");
      QTable.Columns.Add("ans4");

     DataRow dr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
         dr = QTable.NewRow();
         dr[0] =  i;
         dr[1] = "Qno" + i;
         dr[2] = "TST001";
         dr[3] = "TST001";
       //dr[4] = "Is n't so nice to have this test project in place ?";
         dr[4] = "Question";
         dr[5] = "Option1";
         dr[6] = "Option2";
         dr[7] = "Option3";
         dr[8] = "Option45";

            QTable.Rows.Add(dr);
      }

    QuestionSet.Tables.Add(QTable);
   return QuestionSet;

    }
```

On Next button Click

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
     LoadQuestion();
  } 
 protected void LoadQuestion()
  { 
    if (Questions.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0) 
        {
          DataRow DR = Questions.Tables[0].Rows[0]; Question.Text=DR[0].ToString()+" of  "+totalQs; sno = DR[1].ToString();
         Questionlbl.Text = DR[4].ToString();        
         rbtnAns.Items.Clear();rbtnAns.Items.Add(DR[5].ToString());  
         rbtnAns.Items.Add(DR[6].ToString());  
         rbtnAns.Items.Add(DR[7].ToString());
         rbtnAns.Items.Add(DR[8].ToString());
         Question‌​s.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(DR);    
    }
  }
```

What I want is, when user clicks on next button the next question with four option should display ,how should I get this using `datarow`.

Comment: Suraj sir do you have any idea about asked question?

Comment: @NitinTurankar he paha : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671706/next-row-from-dataset-button-only-performing-function-once?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: On next button  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {LoadQuestion();}                                         protected void LoadQuestion()
    {if (Questions.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0){DataRow DR = Questions.Tables[0].Rows[0];
         Question.Text=DR[0].ToString()+" of "+totalQs;
         sno = DR[1].ToString();Questionlbl.Text = DR[4].ToString();
         rbtnAns.Items.Clear();rbtnAns.Items.Add(DR[5].ToString());
        rbtnAns.Items.Add(DR[6].ToString());  rbtnAns.Items.Add(DR[7].ToString());rbtnAns.Items.Add(DR[8].ToString());Questions.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(DR);

Comment: @NitinTurankar Sorry for late reply you need to add `@Name` to comment otherwise no one gets notified about your comment , However consider **Bhavesh** suggestion.

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya sir Any example for datalist

Answer (score 0):

Yes see at follow I have added some sample code. you can try it.
Put this code in your **aspx** page and configure the `datasource` as required.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
        AllowPaging="true"
        AutoGenerateRows="false" 
        DataSourceID="DetailsViewSource">
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblQUestion" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("question") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <input type="radio" name="anwser" value='<%#Eval("ans1") %>'>
                    <label>
                        <%#Eval("ans1") %></label><br />
                    <input type="radio" name="anwser" value='<%#Eval("ans2") %>' />
                    <label>
                        <%#Eval("ans2") %></label><br />
                    <input type="radio" name="anwser" value='<%#Eval("ans3") %>' />
                    <label>
                        <%#Eval("ans3") %></label><br />
                    <input type="radio" name="anwser" value='<%#Eval("ans4") %>' />
                    <label>
                        <%#Eval("ans4") %></label><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Fields>
        <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last"
            NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Previous" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="AliceBlue" ForeColor="HotPink" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DetailsViewSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringKeyHere%>"
        InsertCommand="Your Insert Query" 
        SelectCommand="Your Select Query">
     </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: sir ,in this "<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringKeyHere%>" ConnectionStringKeyHere means our connection string?

Comment: @NitinTurankar this is connection string key value which you have defined in the web.config file.

Comment: Means Name Of That connection String